# Spacing between images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 images side-by-side, I would like to know how to get some spacing between them. I have tried everything, margins, padding and I don't know what to do.

```css
.content1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/album-title.jpg");
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.text1 {
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style", Optima, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 45px;
}
.text2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #6CB9D9;
}
.album1 {
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
}
.album2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
}
.album3 {
  float: right;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
}
.album {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #191919;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  <h3 class="text1">Our Latest Album<span class="slash">   /   </span><span class="text2">Fresh from the house of Music Club Band</span></h3>
</div>
<div class="album">
  <div class="album1">
    <img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA9133-650x385.jpg" alt="album1">
  </div>
  <div class="album2">
    <img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA9099-650x385.jpg" alt="album2">
  </div>
  <div class="album3">
    <img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA0373-650x385.jpg" alt="album3" class="album4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sure you are :) :P :D

Comment: I don't see any margin or padding in your sample.

Comment: @AdamHeeg I tried but it didn't work so i removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your wrapping div's to 31% but you didn't change the size of your images so they were flowing outside the wrappers. If you set Overflow: hidden; on your album1, album2 and album3 div's you'll see that your margins are working on the divs but you'll only see part of your images. if you set the imgs themselves to a width of 100% as below you'll see it works.

```css
.content1 {
  background-image: url("http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/album-title.jpg");
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.text1 {
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style", Optima, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 45px;
}
.text2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #6CB9D9;
}
.album1 {
  float: left;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
}
.album2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
}
.album3 {
  float: right;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1%;
}
.album {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #191919;
}

.album img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  <h3 class="text1">Our Latest Album<span class="slash">   /   </span><span class="text2">Fresh from the house of Music Club Band</span></h3>
</div>
<div class="album">
  <div class="album1">
    <img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA9133-650x385.jpg" alt="album1">
  </div>
  <div class="album2">
    <img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA9099-650x385.jpg" alt="album2">
  </div>
  <div class="album3">
    <img src="http://www.thefreeloves.com/prototype/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/FDA0373-650x385.jpg" alt="album3" class="album4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In each div tag, just place the following style = "margin-right: 20px;". So for example, for the first image, change it ot this

div style = "margin-right: 20px;" class="album1">

Comment: Have you inspected it in a web browser to make sure the setting isn't being over-ridden?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `float`, you can simply set the `display` of the albums to `inline-block`, and set the `text-align` of their parent to `center`. Note that the three images there are too wide to be in one line, so you'll have to adjust that yourself.

```
.album1 img, .album2 img, .album3 img {
     //set img width and height here
}
.album1 {
  display: inline-block;
  //add padding/margin here
}
.album2 {
  display: inline-block;
  //add padding/margin here
}
.album3 {
  display: inline-block;
  //add padding/margin here
}
.album {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #191919;
  text-align:center;
}
```